# Can the absolute Picard functor be trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Consider $\pi : X\rightarrow S$ a separated scheme of finite type over some base scheme $S$. The absolute Picard functor $\operatorname{Pic}_X$ from the category of $S$-schemes to that of abelian groups, is defined by 
$$\operatorname{Pic}_X(T):=\operatorname{Pic}(X_T)=\{\text{isomorphism classes of invertibles sheaves on } X_T=X\times_ST\}$$
It is claimed in every source I met (eg. [on ncatlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Picard+scheme), last paragraph of $2$) that this functor is *never* a separated presheaf in the Zariski topology, since given a non trivial invertible sheaf on $X_T$, it can be made trivial on some Zariski covering $\{T_i\rightarrow T\}$ so that the natural map $\operatorname{Pic}(X_T)\rightarrow \prod_i\operatorname{Pic}(X_{T_i})$ is not injective.

But can we be sure that there always exists a non trivial invertible sheaf on $X_T$ for some suitable $S$-scheme $T$ ? That is, could the Picard functor of some scheme $X$ actually send every $T$ to the trivial group ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $T=\Bbb P^1\times S$. Then $X_T=X\times_S S\times \Bbb P^1=\Bbb P^1\times X$, and denoting $p: \Bbb P^1\times X\to \Bbb P^1$ the projection, we have that $p^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is a nontrivial invertible sheaf on $X_T$.

Comment: I see ! Thank you very much, that is a clever example =)